# Laravelでログインしてから24時間経っているかどうか判断する処理の実装方法

Tags: laravel

現在Laravelで2重投票防止機能としてログインしてから24時間立たないと再投票できない仕組みを作ろうとしています。
モデルの中にlogintimeというメソッドを作ってその中に再投票防止の処理を実装したいです。

Laravel Framework 6.18.20

**ソースコード**
Article.php(モデル)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Article extends Model
{

    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App/User');
    }

    public function getCountVotesAtribute(): int
    {
      return $this->votes->count();
    }

    public function logintime()
    {
　　　　// ここに再投票防止の処理
    }

}
```

usersテーブル（最終ログインの履歴が保存されている）

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('last_login_at')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

**考えたこと**
三項演算子を使ってログインしてから24時間経っている場合はtrueそうでない場合はfalseを返す方法

```
public function logintime(?User $user): bool
    {
      return $user
        ? (bool)$this->votes->where('last_login_at', $user->last_login_at) // 時間の処理をしたい！
        
    }
```

しかし、コレクションの処理で24時間後というのがどうしてもわからず断念しました。

Answer (score 0):

Curbonを使うと日時を簡単に扱えます。Laravelでは追加パッケージなく利用できます
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

ログインして24時間後か判定したいということなので、今から24時間前の日時でwhereBetweenを使うと良いです

```
$ php artisan tinker
>>> use Carbon\Carbon;
>>> $end = Carbon::now(); // 実行した日時(サンプル)
=> Carbon\Carbon @1608306976 {#3330
     date: 2020-12-19 00:56:16.307663 Asia/Tokyo (+09:00),
   }

>>> $start = $end->subHour(24); // 24時間前の日時(サンプル)
=> Carbon\Carbon @1608134176 {#3330
     date: 2020-12-17 00:56:16.307663 Asia/Tokyo (+09:00),
   }

// 24時間以内にログインしているならtrue
>>> User::where("id", 1)->whereBetween("last_login_at", [$start, $end])->exists();
```

クエリを発行せずにlast_login_atで24時間以内かの判定自体はできます。これはCarbonのbetweenメソッドを使用します

```
>>> $end = Carbon::now();
=> Carbon\Carbon @1608307277 {#3340
     date: 2020-12-19 01:01:17.033569 Asia/Tokyo (+09:00),
   }
>>> $start = $end->subHour(24);
=> Carbon\Carbon @1608220877 {#3340
     date: 2020-12-18 01:01:17.033569 Asia/Tokyo (+09:00),
   }
>>> $user->last_login_at->between($start, $end)
=> true or false
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。tinkerは使ったことないので上記の記述をArticle.phpにに直接書いても良いのでしょうか？

Comment: 書いて良いです。コードを使う場合は `use Carbon\Carbon;` の追加を忘れないでください。Laravelでコードの挙動を確認するのに便利なのでtinkerはぜひ試してみてください

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。丁寧にありがとうございます